# in excel how change the value of a cell if it is over a specified amount

Tags: excel

I am making a cost calculator and what I want is a cell to display a converted value based upon a range of values. For example: if the value is > 100mb I want a cell to display $25.00 and if > 200mb than the cell to display $50.00.

Comment: Welcome. Do you want to use formula or macros? Can you give a reproducible example of how your data is organized in the spreadsheet? It helps to address the answer. Thank's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have your mb value in `A1` cell how about something like

```
=FLOOR((A1 - 1) / 100, 1) * 25
```

It will give you (exactly as in your requirements > 100)

```
 A1   B1
--------
 99    0
100    0
101   25
200   25
201   50
```

```
=FLOOR(A1 / 100, 1) * 25
```

It will give you (>= 100)

```
 A1   B1
--------
 99    0
100   25
101   25
200   50
201   50
```

Comment: What worked was =FLOOR ((A1-0/100, 1)*25 THANKS TO YOU I CAN SLEEP NOW HA